Running Kivy app and client concurrently with asyncio
I have no asynchronous knowledge and very little experience with kivy.
What I am attempting to do here is a card game (Phase 10) with a

Kivy GUI
asyncio Server/Client communication

Here is the repository link
-It's messy, I know.
server.py:
import asyncio
import json

from common import Client

clients = {}

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break

        message_json = data.decode()
        message = json.loads(message_json)

        type = None

        try:
            type = message["type"]

        except:
            print("There is no 'type' value in the message.")
            break

        if type == "register":
            new_client = Client(reader,writer)
            new_client.set_client_id(message["client_id"])

            c_id = message["client_id"]
            clients[c_id] = new_client

            print(f"Received message: {message}")
            writer.write(b"Message received: Registered Client {c_id}")
            await writer.drain()

        if type == "get_player":
            print(f"GET PLAYER MESSAGE\n{message}")


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_client, "127.0.0.1", 8888
    )

    async with server:
        print("Server Listening")
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

client.py:
import asyncio
import json

from common import Client


class GameClient(Client):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.make_client_id()

    def add_client(self,client):
        self.reader = client.reader
        self.writer = client.writer
        try:
            self.client_id = client.client_id

        except:
            print("No client_id for GameClient")

    def get_client_id(self):
        return self.client_id

    async def connect(self, addr = "127.0.0.1", port = 8888):
        self.reader,self.writer =  await asyncio.open_connection(addr, port)
        print(f"Client created and connected:\n\t{self.client_id}")


    async def send_message(self, message: dict):
        message_json = json.dumps(message)
        self.writer.write(message_json.encode())
        await self.writer.drain()

    async def register(self):
        message_d = {
            "type": "register",
            "client_id": self.client_id
        }
        await self.send_message(self, message_d)

        data = await self.reader.read(1024)
        message_dict = data.decode()
        # message_dict = json.loads(message_json)
        print(f"Received: {message_dict}")

    async def start_client(self):
        await self.connect()
        await self.register()
        self.writer.close()
        await self.writer.wait_closed()

    async def run(self):
        await self.start_client()
        while True:
            data = await self.reader.read(1024)
            if not data:
                print("No data: breaking...")
                break

            message_dict = data.decode()
            # message_dict = json.loads(message_json)
            print(f"Received: {message_dict}")


gui.py:
import asyncio
import asynckivy as ak

from kivy.app import App, async_runTouchApp
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

from phase10.client import GameClient


class GetPlayerScreen(Screen):

    async def send_five(self):
        message = {"type": "ready", "player": cl.client_id}
        c = loop.create_task(cl.send_message(message))



class Loading(Screen):
    pass


class PageMaster(ScreenManager):
    pass


class PhaseTenApp(App):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.root = PageMaster()
        self.root.add_widget(Loading(name = "loading"))
        self.root.add_widget(GetPlayerScreen(name = "getplayer"))
        self.root.current = "getplayer"
        return self.root


cl = GameClient()
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    async def mainThread():
        p10 = PhaseTenApp()
        b = loop.create_task(p10.async_run())
        a = loop.create_task(cl.run())
        (done, pending) = await asyncio.wait({a}, return_when='FIRST_COMPLETED')

    asyncio.run(mainThread())

.kv:
<Loading>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        AsyncImage:
            source: "./assets/images/CardBack.png"
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}

<GetPlayerScreen>:
    conn_btn: conn_btn
    name_input: name_input
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Name"
        TextInput:
            id: name_input
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                id: conn_btn
                text:"Go!"
            Button:
                text: "1"
                on_press: root.send_five()
            Button:
                text: "2"
                on_press: root.send_five()
            Button:
                text: "3"
                on_press: root.send_five()
            Button:
                text: "4"
                on_press: root.send_five()
            Button:
                text: "5"
                on_press: root.send_five()

The gui is primarily for testing at the moment, I added buttons to test sending various messages to the server once I can run both together.
I've tried a few approaches, but I am not confident I implemented them correctly, so obviously I haven't successfully ran the app and was able to send a message to the server after the I initial 'register' message.
Anyone have an idea and maybe the words to teach me a lesson here?
I've tried having the client and gui separate and run from a shared file. Currently working on having the gui as the client, as I believe I've read this being a decent method to use.
